# Attempting to downgrade from iOS 9.3.5 to iOS 8.4.1 will not work

Tags: ios, ipad, jailbreak, downgrade

I attempted to follow [this](https://www.se7ensins.com/forums/threads/downgrading-from-ios-9-to-8-on-ipad-mini.1684659/#post-13339562) guide for ***Downgrading from iOS 9.3.5 to iOS 8.4.1.***

I was able to complete every step in the list until these step(s):

> [image: insert description here :)]

I get stuck at ***step 20.***

This is when you start the downgrade.

When the downgrade appears, I click **Download and Install** as usual.

But when I click it, it just stays on this screen forever:

[image: Stuck]

The  **Download and Install** button will stay grayed out and will have a spinning wheel.

I am using an iPad mini (1st gen) and am running iOS 9.3.5

For other people, the downgrade will start **immediately.**

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you asked the person that wrote the guide?

Comment: @fsb There is no way to reply to a direct comment. So I wrote a question here. Due to this place being the best place for iOS question's, this is the best forum to start.

Comment: From looking at the comments beneath https://www.reddit.com/r/jailbreak/comments/719v6j/tutorial_downgrade_ios_935_to_841_ota_no_shsh/ it seems that the procedure fails for other people as well

Comment: I was able to do it! Please read the answer!

Comment: So the answer to my question (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/311863/ios-9-3-5-in-ipad-mini-1) is no, don't upgrade?

Comment: @Ihf No. You can upgrade, just if you want to go back, follow the guide in my question! Just log out of iCloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was successfully able to start the downgrade! It turns out that it.....

Drumroll, please! :)

***WAS ICLOUD!***

I was able to start the downgrade to 8.4.1 by signing out of iCloud, then initiating the downgrade!

I hope this helps some people